# ReactJS how to render when changes value

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[when i click add to favourites(adding on local storage but not updating count, when i click button ref, updating count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpJHg.png) i am doing it for my ecommerce project, i have wishlist. When i adding items to my wishlist, i am adding items to my localStorage. And i need to show how many items i added to my wishlist.
i dont know how to render header (automatically) when changes value (localStorage).

i added button, with onClick i am calling cou. when i add items to wishlist nothing happening(not rendering) when i click button everything good.
Can someone help please?
Everything is on header component(page)

```
const [count, setCount] = useState((JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("liked"))));


  const cou = () => {
    let oldData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('liked') || "[]")
    if (oldData.length === count.length) {
      setCount((JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("liked"))))
    } else {
      setCount((JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("liked"))))
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let oldData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('liked') || "[]")
    if (oldData.length === count.length) {
      setCount((JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("liked"))))
    } else {
      setCount((JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("liked"))))
    }
  }, [(count.length)]);
```

This span on header

```
<span style={{ position: 'relative', left: '-21px', top: '-18px' }}>{count.length}</span>}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing `[(count.length)]`, can you check with [count]? Please let me know the output.

Comment: No, useEffect not working :/

Comment: Can you provide a live example so that I can check and tell you? Please provide a Stackblitz link

Comment: Oh, i tried with [count] didnt work. Now i tried again and everything good. Thanks a lot!!!